# why order function not working with window function in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-order-by, window-functions

```
SELECT d.location, d.continent, d.date, d.population, v.new_vaccinations,
SUM(CONVERT(int, v.new_vaccinations)) OVER (PARTITION BY d.location ORDER BY d.location,d.date) AS       rolling_total_vaccinations
FROM PortofolioProject..coviddeaths d
JOIN PortofolioProject..covidvaccinations v
ON d.location = v.location AND d.date = v.date
WHERE d.continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY d.location , d.date
```

the error tells:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 85
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: Which database is this ?

Comment: I see you have two dots on `FROM PortofolioProject..coviddeaths`

Comment: the error message refers to line 85, and there isn't 85 lines of code provided - so my guess is the error isn't in the snippet (which, by itself, has no syntax errors)